# Test driven development and interfaces

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

How would i unit test an interface such as this following simple example:

```
interface My_App_My_Interface
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getInteger();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getString();
}
```

also how would this be organised in my applications test directory:

`tests > My > App > My > InterfaceTest` ??

Comment: What about this interface do you want to test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't test interfaces. you test implementation. interfaces should be checked (by human) if they provide all required functionality

Comment: So if i am creating a system that provides an interface for third party system to use by implementing the interface then i do not provide the tests in my code?

Comment: interfaces CAN'T be tested as there is NO code in interfaces.

Comment: if you provide an interface that means one of two things. you expect someone to implement that interface because you are going to use it. in this case you should mock this interface or create test implementation and test your code that uses that interface. second option is: you provide interface (as a contract) and implementation that will be used by others. in this case you should test your implementation. different thing is to provide documentation. and best way to do it is by create example test cases. but still, there is no way to test an interface

Comment: @piotrek Wrt your second option, why would you provide interface and implementation? Does it not suffice to provide only implementation? i did not get you when you say `contract`.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/142192/why-would-a-programmer-want-to-separate-implementation-from-interface

Answer (score 0):

As piotrek said, you will never test interfaces as they are just a contract, there is no code in there.

For example, with [atoum testing framework](https://github.com/atoum/atoum) you could write for a class that **implements** your interface.

```
namespace mageekguy\atoum\tests;

class TestMyInterfaceImplementation extends atoum\test{
    public function test__construct(){
        $object = new MyObject();
        $this->object($object)->instanceof('MyInterface');
    }
    public function test_getInteger(){
       $object = new MyObject();
        $this->integer($object->getInteger);
    }
 }
```

As an interface just provides abstract methods, they just can't be instanciated so no test can be written.